# HTML display child div in new line when it exceeds parent div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**CHECK** [DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQVEaO)

I am trying bring the child div element to a new line when the parent div's width exceeds.I tried display:flex ,but when the parent width is exceeded the child div does not come to a new line.Like a bootstrap class row when the child div elements exceeds width of parent element it should be placed in new line.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="wrap">
      <div class="block">Block 1</div>
      <div class="block">Block 2</div>
      <div class="block">Block 3</div>
      <div class="block">Block 4</div>
      <div class="block">Block 5</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap
{
  width:140px;
  display:flex;
  background:yellow;
}
.block
{
  margin-right:5px;
  width:70px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.wrap
{
  width:140px;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  display: flex;
  background:yellow;
}
.block
{
  margin-right:5px;
  width:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
      <div class="block">Block 1</div>
      <div class="block">Block 2</div>
      <div class="block">Block 3</div>
      <div class="block">Block 4</div>
      <div class="block">Block 5</div>
</div>
```

Check this code.You can use `flex-flow: row wrap` with `display:flex`

Answer (score 3):

The default with `display: flex;` is to not allow the children to wrap - try adding the `flex-wrap: wrap;` property to your `.wrap` selector

Comment: I tried it what happens is even though the parent elements width is not exceeded child element goes to new line

Comment: The width is exceeded, though - there is a margin as well on your inner elements, so they each end up being 75px in width - so you cannot fit two on the same line.

Comment: I increased with of wrap to 200px..but still not working

Comment: With this CSS for the .wrap selector: `.wrap{width:200px;display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap;background:yellow;}` it certainly does wrap in your example.

Comment: yeah it worked now...Before i replaced the display:flex with flex-wrap:wrap instead of adding it..